# html5: putting two bordered text inside another border with a button click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a bordered text + image that is generated once a button (`button1`) is clicked. Now, I click another button (`button2`) and another bordered text+image is generated. But this time (when button2 is pressed), I want to put the two bordered text+image combo inside another border. How do I do that? My code currently looks like

```
.borderexample{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#287EC7;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 20%;
}
p:after {
    margin-right: 1em;
    content: "";
}
img:before {
    margin-left: 1em;
    content: "";
}
```

HTML:

```
    <section class="borderexample" id="data_zone">

    </section> 
    <section class="borderexample" id="data_zone2">

    </section>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("data_zone2").style.display="none";
    $('#button1').click(function () {
              var color = document.getElementById("txtNameDist").value;
              document.querySelector('#data_zone').innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="imgABC" src="imgABC.png" />';

            })
            $('#button2').click(function () {
              var color = document.getElementById("txtNameDist").value;

              document.getElementById("data_zone2").style.display="block";
              document.querySelector('#data_zone2').innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="imgXYZ" src="imgXYZ.png" />';

            })
        </script>
```

Current result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyTzd.jpg)
But desired result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haSLO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

throw your two sections in a div with an id you like, e.g. `id="Container"` and with jquery (which it looks like you're using), you can just add a class to that containing div that has the styles you want. like this:

```
$("#data_zone2").hide();
$('#button1').click(function () {
          var color = $("#txtNameDist").val();
          $('#data_zone').html('<p><strong>' + color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="imgABC" src="imgABC.png" />');

        })
        $('#button2').click(function () {
          var color = $("#txtNameDist").val();

          $("#data_zone2").hide();
          $('#data_zone2').html('<p><strong>' + color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="imgXYZ" src="imgXYZ.png" />');
          $('#Container').addClass('fancy-border-stuff');
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `section`s in an element with the class that defines your border (`.borderexample`)

```css
.borderexample{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#287EC7;
}
div.borderexample {
  padding: 2em;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 20%;
}
p:after {
    margin-right: 1em;
    content: "";
}
img:before {
    margin-left: 1em;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="borderexample">
  <section class="borderexample" id="data_zone">

  </section>
  <section class="borderexample" id="data_zone2">

  </section>
</div>
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    document.getElementById("data_zone2").style.display = "none";
    $("#button1").on("click", function() {
      var color = "color";
      document.querySelector("#data_zone").innerHTML =
        "<p><strong>" +
        color +
        "</strong></p>" +
        '<img id="imgABC" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg" />';
    });
    $("#button2").click(function() {
      var color = "color";
  
      document.getElementById("data_zone2").style.display = "block";
      document.querySelector("#data_zone2").innerHTML =
        "<p><strong>" +
        color +
        "</strong></p>" +
        '<img id="imgXYZ" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg" />';
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: when you press button1, there should be only one border. The 2nd outer border won't be there. The 2nd outer border comes only when you press the button2